# Accessing Vlookup Macro Code in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, worksheet-function

I wish to manually code VLOOKUP in python, so is it possible to see the VBA code behind VLOOKUP?
I remember a presentation in my school by a guest speaker showing that the Excel Functions are just macro/vba codes. Can someone please show me the way to view the code for Excel Worksheet functions?

Comment: He may have been showing your vba code that was equivalent to VLOOKUP, but I'm sure all the Excel Worksheet functions are done in C.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a way to view the XL code for VLOOKUP (its almost certainly written in C).
 The basic algorithms used in VLOOKUP are Linear Search for unsorted data, and Binary Search for sorted data. There are many examples available on the web of implementing these algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Excel functions i dont' know, but to Excel Add-ins it's possible.

Add a add-in to your excel application, and go to Visual Basic Editor, double click in add-in and use this passwords.

Add-in                    --  Password

1. Internet Assistant VBA --  Weezaarde!?
2. Autosave Addin         --  Wildebeest!!
3. Analysis Toolpak VBA   --  Wildebeest!!
4. Solver Add-in          --  Wildebeest!!

All forms be design in excel forms sheets used in older versions of Excel.

[]'s