# Excel Vlookup in Python

Tags: python, excel

How do I implement the Excel VLOOKUP worksheet function in Python. Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Vlookup Macro Code in Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130199/accessing-vlookup-macro-code-in-excel)

Comment: What do you mean, 'implement'? Do you want to access an existing worksheet and calculate something via `vlookup`, or do you just want to replicate the functionality in something?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using xlrd to read your Excel XLS file:

Get the key column values that need to be searched on:

`key_values = sheet.col_values(KEY_COLX, start_rowx=START_ROWX, end_rowx=END_ROWX)`
`# UPPER_CASE variables (KEY_COLX etc) are part of your problem description.`

Search those values to find what you are looking for:

```
# example here is exact match
try:
    found_offset = key_values.index(QUERY_VALUE)
except IndexError:
    # not found
    # do something else
```

Then you pick out the data cell you want e.g.

`sheet.cell(START_ROWX + found_offset, KEY_COLX + DATA_OFFSET)`

Not using xlrd? See [here.](http://www.python-excel.org)